# Getting CodeLens to work with GitHub projects

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2015, codelens

I'm working with a small GitHub repo (mostly just playing around) but I've noticed that CodeLens features (save references) don't seem to be working with my GitHub repo:

[image]

There are definitely changes as indicated by:

[image]

Am I missing a configuration setting somewhere?  Ideally, I'd like to see the authors, changes, and any other information that would be provided by CodeLens in a TFS setting.